# Count matches between two arrays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

How can I count the number of entries two arrays have in common, using just standard excel formulae (i.e. no VBA)?

Can't find an answer anywhere.

e.g.

```
      A   B
 +-------------
1|    1   10
2|    2   11
3|    3   12
4|    4   13
5|    5   14
6|    6   1
7|    7   3
8|    8   17
```

What function can I give `A1:A7` and `B1:B7` as arguments to, and get `2` as a result back (because they both have `1` and `3` in common).

Comment: What result would you expect if `a = [1 2 3 4 5]` and `b = [10 11 3 3 15]`  Is that one match or two?

Comment: for the data i have each column has only distinct values, so it doesn't matter for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [sumproduct](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) like this -

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A8,B1:B8))
```

It will handle the `countif` as an **array** and compare all elements instead of matching positions.